# Octal equivalent in C#

Tags: c#, .net, numbers

In C language octal number can be written by placing `0` before number e.g.

```
 int i = 012; // Equals 10 in decimal.
```

I found the equivalent of hexadecimal in C# by placing `0x` before number e.g.

```
 int i = 0xA; // Equals 10 in decimal.
```

Now my question is: 
**Is there any equivalent of octal number in C# to represent any value as octal?**

Comment: @RenniePet: 0o would have been nice.

Comment: Something maybe of interest on Software Engineering SE for the "why" behind this: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/98733

Answer (score 62, accepted):

No, there are no octal number literals in C#.

For strings: `Convert.ToInt32("12", 8)` returns `10`.

Answer (score 39):

No there isn't, the language specification (ECMA-334) is quite specific.

[4th edition, page 72](https://www.ecma-international.org/wp-content/uploads/ECMA-334_4th_edition_june_2006.pdf)

> ### 9.4.4.2 Integer literals
>
> Integer literals are used to write values of types int, uint, long,
> and ulong. Integer literals have two  possible forms: decimal and
> hexadecimal.

No octal form.

Comment: Update: C# 7 and above now also supports _binary_ literals, such as `0b10` for decimal `2`.

Comment: @mklement0 Odd. The current [6th ed. spec](https://www.ecma-international.org/wp-content/uploads/ECMA-334_6th_edition_june_2022.pdf) (section 6.4.5.3 Integer Literals) still makes no mention of that at all.

Comment: @GeneralGrievance, that is odd indeed, but I don't know what the exact relationship between the _spec_ and Microsoft's _implementation_ of it is. Binary integer literals _are_ described in the C# docs, namely [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/integral-numeric-types).

Comment: @mklement0 Ah, I just found Microsoft's own 7.0 spec [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/readme), and the link to "Integer Literals" does indeed mention binary (still no octal of course).

Answer (score 24):

No, there are no octal literals in C#.

If necessary, you could pass a string and a base to [`Convert.ToInt32`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k20k614.aspx), but it's obviously nowhere near as nice as a literal:

```
int i = Convert.ToInt32("12", 8);
```

Answer (score 9):

No, there are no octal numbers in C#.

Use `public static int ToInt32(string value, int fromBase);`

```
fromBase
Type: System.Int32
The base of the number in value, which must be 2, 8, 10, or 16.
```

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k20k614.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

You can't use literals, but you can parse an octal number: `Convert.ToInt32("12", 8)`.