# Convert oct to dex integer

Tags: c#, oop

Incorrectly converts a number
In the program you need to convert from octal number system to decimal
"a" is a integer class field that uses the GetDex() method
Construct - this.a = a;

```
public int GetDex()
{
    int res = 0;
    int exp = 1;
   
    for (int i = Convert.ToString(a).Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        res += exp * Convert.ToInt32(Convert.ToString(a)[i]);
        exp *= 8;
    }

    return res;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `Convert.ToInt32(a, 8)` see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4247037/octal-equivalent-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the

```
Convert.ToInt32(Convert.ToString(a)[i])
```

fragment. You actually add *ascii codes*, not *digits*. To get digit *integer* `5` from *character* `'5'` just subtract `'0'`:

```
(Convert.ToString(a)[i] - '0')
```

Your code *corrected*:

```
public int GetDex() 
{
    int res = 0;
    int exp = 1;

    for (int i = Convert.ToString(a).Length - 1; i >= 0; i--) 
    {
        //DONE: you should add digits, not ascii codes: - '0'
        res += exp * (Convert.ToString(a)[i] - '0');
        exp *= 8;
    }

    return res;
}
```

You can put it compact with a help of *Linq*:

```
public int GetDex() => a
  .ToString()
  .Aggregate(0, (s, i) => s * 8 + i - '0');
```